# Call to undefined method Directory::create() when seeding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker, laravel-seeding

I am trying to seed a database in Laravel. I am using faker to seed the database but I am getting the following error.

```
Call to undefined method Directory::create()
```

Below is the code I have written in the table seed file.  Basically, I want to create a seed of names and telephone numbers.
Below is the code I have written.

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
 use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class DirectoriesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
   /**
   * Run the database seeds.
  *
   * @return void
  */
 public function run()
  {
       //Directory::truncate();
       $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
      for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        Directory::create([
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'number' => $faker->PhoneNumber,
        ]);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your `Directory ` class. Is that a model extending eloquent model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the model in top of file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use App\Directory;
```

Or call the model with its namespace

```
App\Directory::create([
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'number' => $faker->PhoneNumber,
]);
```

And edit your `$fillable` propetry's definition in  model

It should be  `protected` instead of `protect`

```
 class Category extends Model
 {
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'number'];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `Directory` is a model here.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use App\Directory;
....
```

Comment: I have just run that and now I am getting the following error in my model.

Comment: ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protect' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)```

Comment: my model is as follows: ```class Directory extends Model
{
    protect $fillable = ['name', 'number'];
}```

Comment: ```protect``` must be ```protected```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience. Make sure, the Php Curl is installed and enabled before performing any seed operation. You can install and enable by typing following command.

```
sudo apt install php-curl
```